# SSRS 2008 will not load when using firefox XML Parsing Error: no element found Line Number 1, Column 1:

Tags: firefox, reporting-services

When trying to access SSRS 2008 with firefox it loads either with a blank screen or with the following error:

XML Parsing Error: no element found
Location: http://[mySSRSserver]/Reports/Pages/Folder.aspx
Line Number 1, Column 1:

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Type `about:config` in the address bar [press return/enter]
2. In "Search" type `negotiate`
3. Find `network.negotiate-auth.trusted-uris` and double click
4. Type in your SSRS server `http://[mySSRSserver]` and click OK
5. Restart Firefox and `http://[mySSRSserver]/Reports/Pages/Folder.aspx` should load, you might also have to add the value to `network.negotiate-auth.delegation-uris`